asdf: after modifying downloaded code of a plugin, how do I then use asdf in the normal way?
asdf install erlang 12.3.4.11 failed to compile due to openssl 3.0 having removed FIPS_mode.
By setting the environment variable KERL_AUTOCLEAN=0 the sources are preserved and I was able to fix the problem with a simple stub function in pkey.c.
I then ran make and make install, but asdf doesn't know I have this version of erlang installed. Clearly running make install was the wrong thing to do.
What should I do after running make to have normal asdf behaviour?

One thing you could do is to commit the fix in a local git repository, and then ask asdf to install Erlang from there.  As mentioned in the documentation, it would be something like:
export OTP_GITHUB_URL=/path/to/my/repo
asdf install erlang ref:my_fixed_branch

Even though the name of the environment variable suggests that it needs to be a Github URL, providing a local directory seems to work too.
